# Table border:0 not working

Tags: css, border

I can't for the life of me get rid of table borders. I've tried the following code in both [style.css](http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/wp-content/themes/perkins/style.css) and [custom.css](http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/wp-content/themes/perkins/assets/css/custom.css)

```
article table {width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;}
article table td, article table th {padding: 5px; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;}
```

I've also tried border: 0px and I've tried leaving out "article" in front of table - still no effect.

You can see how stupid it looks [here](http://www.theveggietable.com/blog/vegetarian-recipes/soups/eggplant-and-black-bean-chili/).

Comment: In FF i didn´t see any problem...can you describe it?

Comment: Chrome, FF, and IE show no borders... what is the problem ?

Comment: No borders there my friend... try clearing your browser cache!

Comment: I've cleared cache a thousand times, but I'll take your word for it - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the 1px gray borders around all the table cells, it appears to be coming from this definition in your style.css file:

```
article table td,article table th{padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;}
```

Comment: Just remove the border part of that definition and they go away.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about, and that's what I've changed. I've cleared my browser cache as well as the style.css cache in CloudFlare, and when I view style.css in the browser it shows my changes, but the borders are still there. Meanwhile, others say they don't see any borders.

Comment: If you have the Cloudflare plugin installed in WordPress, try putting it into development mode temporarily to see if that clears up the issue. If it does, then it seems like it's an issue with a stale file in Cloudflare. I also mentioned in a different answer that if you have any caching plugins activated in WordPress you might want to try purging their cache as well.

EDIT: I actually just refreshed your page again and the borders are now gone.

Comment: It was a caching problem. I'd cleared the css files and my browser to no avail, but once I cleared the entire site cache in both CloudFlare and WordFence, it finally took.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same definitions of `article table td, article table th` in both files - one with border, second without it. Probably you are loading custom.css before style.css. Load custom.css after style.css to override style and remove border.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I'm seeing the borders but others aren't is making me suspect there's a caching issue going on. I noticed the site appears to be using WordPress. Do you have any caching plugins turned on and enabled? If you made changes to style.css it's possible that it's serving up a previous version from the cache. Try clearing the cache with any plugins you're using and then refreshing the page.